# how to returns a dictionary of letters from a to z mapped to their corresponding shifted alphabet

Tags: python-3.x

My answer was almost right, but there are some characters not in the specific key I want. I have no ideas why this is happening.

```
def caesar_dict(shift_amount):
    list = {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d', 'e':'e', 'f':'f', 'g':'g', 'h':'h', 'i':'i', 'j':'j', 'k':'k', 'l':'l', 'm':'m', 'n':'n',
           'o':'o', 'p':'p', 'q':'q', 'r':'r', 's':'s', 't':'t', 'u':'u', 'v':'v', 'w':'w', 'x':'x', 'y':'y', 'z':'z'}
    for key in list.keys():
        if shift_amount > 0:
            if ord(key)+shift_amount > 122:
                list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount - 26)]
            else:
                list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount)]
        elif shift_amount < 0:
            if ord(key)+shift_amount < 97:
                list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount + 26)]
            else:
                list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount)]
        elif shift_amount == 0:
            return list
    return list
```

My answer:

```
Testing caesar_dict() for 5: {'c': 'h', 'j': 'o', 'y': 'd', 'n': 's', 'd': 'i', 'k': 'p', 'u': 'z', 'b': 'g', 'w': 'g', 'e': 'o', 'f': 'p', 'r': 'g', 'm': 'g', 'z': 'o', 'q': 'v', 'g': 'l', 'x': 'h', 'p': 'z', 'a': 'p', 't': 'd', 'i': 's', 'v': 'p', 'o': 'd', 'h': 'g', 's': 'h', 'l': 'v'}
Testing caesar_dict() for 0: {'c': 'c', 'j': 'j', 'y': 'y', 'n': 'n', 'd': 'd', 'k': 'k', 'u': 'u', 'b': 'b', 'w': 'w', 'e': 'e', 'f': 'f', 'r': 'r', 'm': 'm', 'z': 'z', 'q': 'q', 'g': 'g', 'x': 'x', 'p': 'p', 'a': 'a', 't': 't', 'i': 'i', 'v': 'v', 'o': 'o', 'h': 'h', 's': 's', 'l': 'l'}
Testing caesar_dict() for -1: {'c': 'b', 'j': 'i', 'y': 'x', 'n': 'm', 'd': 'b', 'k': 'i', 'u': 't', 'b': 'a', 'w': 'v', 'e': 'b', 'f': 'b', 'r': 'q', 'm': 'l', 'z': 'x', 'q': 'p', 'g': 'b', 'x': 'v', 'p': 'o', 'a': 'x', 't': 's', 'i': 'h', 'v': 't', 'o': 'm', 'h': 'b', 's': 'q', 'l': 'i'}
```

Comment: You might want to look at `%`, for example `-1 % 26 == 25` or `28 % 26 == 2`. So you could do something like `chr((i+shift_amount) % 26 + 97)` instead of horrible case distinctions.

Comment: The answers you get depend (in part) on the quality of the question you ask. The title sort of poses a question, but that doesn't seem to be the one you want (and probably got) answered: an implied "How can my approach/code be fixed?". Heed [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ask a specific, answerable question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're both using `list` as well as modifying `list` at the same time. So in some cases it's not using the original character at a particular position but already a new character.

If you construct a new result it works as expected:

```
def caesar_dict(shift_amount):
    list = {'a':'a', 'b':'b', 'c':'c', 'd':'d', 'e':'e', 'f':'f', 'g':'g', 'h':'h', 'i':'i', 'j':'j', 'k':'k', 'l':'l', 'm':'m', 'n':'n',
           'o':'o', 'p':'p', 'q':'q', 'r':'r', 's':'s', 't':'t', 'u':'u', 'v':'v', 'w':'w', 'x':'x', 'y':'y', 'z':'z'}
    new_list = {}
    for key in list.keys():
        if shift_amount > 0:
            if ord(key)+shift_amount > 122:
                new_list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount - 26)]
            else:
                new_list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount)]
        elif shift_amount < 0:
            if ord(key)+shift_amount < 97:
                new_list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount + 26)]
            else:
                new_list[key] = list[chr(ord(key) + shift_amount)]
        elif shift_amount == 0:
            new_list = list
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

list_ = {char: char for char in ascii_lowercase}
```

The problem with your code is overwriting the global for list. But on a side note, you can make that dictionary using the string module. ascii_lowercase is a string 'abc...z'. You can then just zip it together with a dictionary comprehension.